# Gerund or Compound verb

Tags: verbs, gerunds, auxiliary-verbs

In the sentence "He is playing for Australia".
"is playing" seems to be the verb
But isn't "playing" a gerund here as it is the complement of the verb "is"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerunds are nouns.  If a person ***was*** a gerund, it would be a rare usage.  Maybe hyperbole, like "Fred Astaire ***is*** dancing." (with emphasis included)